# Julia, efficient way to create a DataFrame by applying a function to tuple elements

Tags: dataframe, performance, tuples, julia

I need to use some data stored in a named tuple to create a dataframe with the same column number and names of the tuple element, by applying a function to them. For example:

```py
    a = (A = [1, 2], B = 1:6)
    f(a) = begin
        df = DataFrame()
        for k in keys(a) df[k] = sample(a[k], 10) end # There could be any other function in place of sample()
        df
    end
```

but if I run @code_warntype I get Union types which I understand means the compiler cannot predict the type before run time and this impacts performance:

```
julia> @code_warntype f(a)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Const(f)
  a::NamedTuple{(:A, :B), Tuple{Vector{Int64}, UnitRange{Int64}}}
  @_3::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Symbol, Int64}}
  df::DataFrame
  k::Symbol

Body::DataFrame
1 ─       (df = Main.DataFrame())
│   %2  = Main.keys(a)::Core.Const((:A, :B))
│         (@_3 = Base.iterate(%2))
│   %4  = (@_3::Core.Const((:A, 2)) === nothing)::Core.Const(false)
│   %5  = Base.not_int(%4)::Core.Const(true)
└──       goto #4 if not %5
2 ┄ %7  = @_3::Tuple{Symbol, Int64}::Tuple{Symbol, Int64}
│         (k = Core.getfield(%7, 1))
│   %9  = Core.getfield(%7, 2)::Int64
│   %10 = Base.getindex(a, k)::Union{UnitRange{Int64}, Vector{Int64}}
│   %11 = Main.sample(%10, 10)::Vector{Int64}
│         Base.setindex!(df, %11, k)
│         (@_3 = Base.iterate(%2, %9))
│   %14 = (@_3 === nothing)::Bool
│   %15 = Base.not_int(%14)::Bool
└──       goto #4 if not %15
3 ─       goto #2
4 ┄       return df
```

The question is: what is the most efficient way to write `f(a)`?
In my specific case all the columns of the dataframe will have the same type, could this information help the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the data and only at the last step, convert it to `DataFrame`. There are multiple ways how it can be done, one of them is `map`, which is type stable for tuples

```
function g(a)
    map(x -> sample(x, 10), a) |> DataFrame
end

julia> @code_warntype(g(a))
MethodInstance for g(::NamedTuple{(:A, :B), Tuple{Vector{Int64}, UnitRange{Int64}}})
  from g(a) in Main at REPL[103]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(g)
  a::NamedTuple{(:A, :B), Tuple{Vector{Int64}, UnitRange{Int64}}}
Locals
  #47::var"#47#48"
Body::DataFrame
1 ─      (#47 = %new(Main.:(var"#47#48")))
│   %2 = #47::Core.Const(var"#47#48"())
│   %3 = Main.map(%2, a)::NamedTuple{(:A, :B), Tuple{Vector{Int64}, Vector{Int64}}}
│   %4 = (%3 |> Main.DataFrame)::DataFrame
└──      return %4
```

Comment: Thank you! strangely enough your code is slightly slower than mine:  1.229 μs vs 956.333 ns with similar memory allocation. but it's more concise and the difference is non-relevant. How does map() know about the tuple element names??